# Database disk image is malformed in MonoTouch

Tags: ios, multithreading, sqlite, xamarin.ios

I am using Monotouch 5 to develop a multithreaded messaging application. After some days of operation, some customers receive the error `Database disk image is malformed`. I am using the [SQLite.cs](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-net/) from Kueger Systems I found in the internet to access the SQLite database.

It appears there is an issue woth multiple threads accessing the database (which happens a lot). I have read somewhere about an option how the database is compiled (Single thread, multi thread, serialized). Do I specify that somehow?

I want to continue updating the database from background threads, without corrupting it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can tell **sqlite** how to deal with multithreading. The trick is to do it **very** early in your application (because once sqlite is initialized it will be too late to change it).

For SQLite.cs you can do this using [this](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-net/source/diff?spec=svn24&r=24&format=side&path=/trunk/src/SQLite.cs) code.

In `Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll` you can call `Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.SetConfig (Mono.Data.Sqlite.SQLiteConfig.*);` to do the same.

In both case the valid values (for the config enum) are documented [here](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_config_getmalloc.html).

Comment: I am using SQLite.cs, so I issued the following statement as the first line in FinishedLaunching: Console.WriteLine(SQLite.SQLite3.Config(SQLite.SQLite3.ConfigOption.MultiThread)); However it returns 21. What does this mean? I cannot find it in the Result enum. Did I do it too early?

Comment: `#define SQLITE_MISUSE      21   /* Library used incorrectly */` My guess is *not early enough* (can't see how too early would be an issue). Did you put this at the start of your `FinishedLaunching` method ?

Comment: Yes, this is the first line of FinishedLaunching. Do I need to do something before that? Is it too early? (e.g. need to specify db path first)?

Comment: AFAIK it **cannot** be too soon. When does the error (21) occurs ? Also `MultiThread` might not mean what you want. E.g. you can't share a single connection between multiple threads, each must have it's own (you might want to try `Serialized`). Read http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have also tried using Serialized, it seems more appropriate. However, the above Console.Writeline outputs 21. It is the first line of code executed in my project, just below FinishedLaunching. What could be happening?

Comment: Also, I noticed from your link that the default mode is Serialized, which means the database can be accessed from multiple threads without getting corrupted. Right?

Comment: Sorry I don't know for `SQLite.cs`. When using `Mono.Data.Sqlite` assembly this line `Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.SetConfig (Mono.Data.Sqlite.SQLiteConfig.Serialized);` does not throw an exception, meaning that the return value was `0`. Also note that `Serialized` will be default **only** if Apple used the default Makefile settings (don't bet on it ;-).

Comment: @poupou : I've got the same problem on Android here. Using your Andr.Unit project (which is great by the way), if I put a `Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.SetConfig (Mono.Data.Sqlite.SQLiteConfig.Serialized);` on the first line of `MainActivity.OnCreate` I do get a `Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException` stating `Library used incorrectly`. I've tried the 3 possible enum values with the same result...

Comment: @SébastienNussbaumer Sorry but I'm not sure what's the default for Android (on iOS sqlite is not compiled with it's *normal* default options) nor exactly which version Android ships (I assume it varies with Android versions too). You better ask a new question specific to Android.