# Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.SetConfig throws a Library used incorrectly exception

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

Using Xamarin.Android, I've tried to play with a sqlite database using the Mono.Data.Sqlite package (using a Nexus 7).

Everything was fine until I tried to use multiple threads, then I got either a corrupted database or various exceptions locking the database (meaning I had to stop and restart the application to be able to access the db again).

As recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307797/database-disk-image-is-malformed-in-monotouch/9312257?noredirect=1#comment21831178_9312257) I've tried to execute the following code as early as possible in my app :

```
Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.SetConfig (Mono.Data.Sqlite.SQLiteConfig.Serialized);
```

But I get an Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException on that line stating :

```
Library used incorrectly
```

I've tried the 3 possible vales for the enum (SingleThreaded, Serialized, MultiThreaded) with the same outcome.

Is this method working at all ?

---

Edit : I fixed my source problem (those nasty infinite loop, I'll never get rid of that ...), so no need to play with the threading config for me anymore.

I'll leave the question open for others though, as the problem is still here, and was experimented by others ([cf the comments on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9312257/7059))

Comment: +1. Doesn't matter where to call it. In Android.Application subclass, OnCreate of starting activity or just button click.

Comment: Well, it does matter actually: it should be before sqlite3_initialize(). Proof http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/config.html.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I've found the SQLite to be extremely touchy to trying to access when a write is done against the database. That being said, I don't write against mine very much. However I did want to mention that you may have luck with readable access and multiple threads. If your not already doing so I recommend calling to it with the explicit paths for write/read. I use this in my code to simplify,

```
         protected SQLiteConnection ReadableDB
         {
             get{return new SQLiteConnection(ReadableDatabase.Path);}
          }

         protected SQLiteConnection WriteableDB
         {
             get{return new SQLiteConnection(WritableDatabase.Path);
         }
```